# Codeigniter route['(:any)'] not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Simple controller so far:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'login/index';
```

From my understanding anything typed into the address bar gets routed to the `Login` controller using the index method? Am I understanding this correctly?

Result: `Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.`

Comment: Not exactly. I think :any just matches the first URI segment.

Comment: @BrianGottier Actually, `(:any)` will match literally any string typed in URL whether it has slash[es] or not. Problem probably exists because this route should be set at latest position/line after predefined ones (default, 404_override, translate_uri_dashes). [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes).

Comment: Regardless, why would anyone do this? Maybe @RobertRocha will let us know.

Comment: I was just testing out the routes feature while reading https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html which states " (:any) will match a segment containing any character" but for some reason when I type anything into the address bar it does not route to 'login/index'

Comment: sidenote: I removed all other routes when testing